# SDWebImage in a simple test app crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

In Xcode 5.0.2

1. I create [a blank single view app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/sdImage) for iPhone,
2. then add a "male.png" image to the project,
3. drag a UIImageView to the storyboard
4. and finally add the following code to the `viewDidLoad`:

   `_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"];`

This works well:

[image: simulator screenshot]

Then I add the files from [SDWebImage project](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and change the [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/sdImage/sdImage/ViewController.m) to:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

static NSString* const kAvatar = @"http://gravatar.com/avatar/55b3816622d935e50098bb44c17663bc.png";

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"male.png"]];
}

@end
```

Unfortunately, this results in app crash with the error message:

```
2014-01-11 19:21:57.731 sdImage[2563:70b] -[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a5aa80
2014-01-11 19:21:57.745 sdImage[2563:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a5aa80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017d6903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172990b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x017294ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   sdImage                             0x00002b43 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 227
    6   UIKit                               0x0033e318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    7   UIKit                               0x0033e5b4 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x002669fd -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00266d97 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    10  UIKit                               0x0026702d -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    11  UIKit                               0x0027189a -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    12  UIKit                               0x00224cd0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1851
    13  UIKit                               0x002293a8 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    14  UIKit                               0x0023d87c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    15  UIKit                               0x0023dde9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    16  UIKit                               0x0022b025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x036e02f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x036dfe01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016b4d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016b4a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x016df77c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  UIKit                               0x00228add -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    25  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    26  sdImage                             0x00002ffd main + 141
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7770d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Why does it happen please? While adding the framework files I have set the checkbox to copy the files.

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried the following:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git
```

then built that project (SDWebImage.xcodeproj) and closed it.

Then I have reopened in Xcode my project (sdImage.xcodeproj) and dragged the SDWebImage.xcodeproj file into it.

After that I have tried to add a **Target Dependency**, but it doesn't show anything named "SDWebImage" there:

[image: screenshot]

Here the [full sized screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX6Hp.png).

And I can not add an "SDWebImage.framework" under **Link Binary With Libraries**, because nothing named "SDWebImage" is there.

Comment: Try adding the following to your "Other Linker Flags" in build settings:  "-force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libSDWebImageARC.a"

Comment: When I download any of zip archives from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases then there is no `libSDWebImageARC.a` file there. Just several headers and an `SDWebImage` file.

Comment: I dont understand what is your problem. The project in github is working fine and loading your avtar in it

Comment: +1 for checking out my project. That works now (since few minutes), because I have finally figured out how to integrate SDWebImage.framework in my project with the help of CocoaPods - please see my own answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just include the SDWebImage source files in your main project? This is how I incorporated SDWebImage, and the SDWebImage docs themselves state: "There are two ways to use this in your project: *copy all the files into your project*, or import the project as a static library." If you do this there is no need to open the SDWebImage project, compile the framework, link the framework with your project, etc.

Comment: Because... I haven't thought about it! :-) I will try your suggestion, thanks

Comment: I have tried your super simple suggestion and it has just worked: https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/sdImageCopied

Comment: Haha, I'm glad it worked! Honestly, I'm an iOS newbie myself, and since my solution was so simple I figured I must be missing something. I almost didn't share it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the project by using CocoaPods with the following [Podfile](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/sdImage/Podfile):

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

and then running `pod install` and opening `sdImage.xcworkspace` in Xcode.

I'm still interested in how to use SDWebImage in a project - without using CocoaPods...